# Hibernate validator and spring versions compatibility

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-validator

We are using hibernate validator version 5.2.5.Final with spring version 5.0.15RELEASE to validate the input data along with bean-io framework.

Now we are planning to upgrade the hibernate validator to latest version 6.1.5 to improve the performance of the workflow.

Kindly provide the compatible version of spring framework version with latest hibernate validator.

Answer (score 0):

The following part of the [documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework/spring-context/latest/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/LocalValidatorFactoryBean.html) will give you a hint.

> **As of Spring 5.0, this class requires Bean Validation 1.1+, with special support for Hibernate Validator 5.x** (see `setValidationMessageSource(org.springframework.context.MessageSource)`). This class is also *runtime-compatible with Bean Validation 2.0 and Hibernate Validator 6.0*, with one special note: If you'd like to call BV 2.0's `getClockProvider()` method, obtain the native `ValidatorFactory` through `#unwrap(ValidatorFactory.class)` and call the `getClockProvider()` method on the returned native reference there.